# how can i install jbpm 6 without using build.xml

Tags: jboss, workflow, jbpm

Can anyone help me to install and configure  JBPM by hand without using the script build.XML of the installer actually i have already jboss AS 7.1 server and i've installed jbpm plugin for eclipse Kepler. And when I run the hello world project I got an error " runtimeManagerFactory was not initialized " even when I add the persistence .XML under the META-INF

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually install jBPM on as7, you'll need to download the kie-wb distribution for as7 and install that into as7.  You might want to make sure to configure the datasource and security domain correctly.

For eclipse, you can just install the plugins from the update site directly, and then configure a jBPM runtime.  I'm not sure which "Hello world" project you're referring to?  I'd recommend creating a new jBPM project, that contains a (simple or advanced) example out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

JBPM6 is an open source document track system,which is used to track the documents. We can also install `jbpm` & `jboss`.
Use this link below, it would be helpful for you to install jboss and jbpm.
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html#d0e780